# How does django knows a http request is authenticated?

Tags: django, web

Suppose a user loggs in a django site.

For subsequent requests, django knows it's the same user.
How does it know that?

Does user (browser) sends a id of some sort? 
If so, what prevents that a malicious user could try a random id to log in as the user?

I'm trying to convert this app to use django.
The app gave a token (id of some sort) to a user id, and user attached it to http-header for all subsequent requests.

Am I doing the essentially same thing if I convert the app to talk to django?

**EDIT**

I want a layman's explanation and trying to make one myself.

When user logs in, server generate an id (session_key in django world).
Server can identify a user by this id.

Server gives this id to client by form of cookie  (`response.set_cookie(cookie_name, id)`)

Client sends this cookie to the server on every request as a cookie.
(I guess programmer doesn't need to do anything to send the cookie to the server)

Cookie expires at some future which is set by the django server.
(Is it possible to prevent expiring?)

So Django is basically doing the same thing as I described in the question(difference is one is cookie and one is http header), and have the same problem described there I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of "cookies"? ;)

Also have a search on Django´s decorator `@login_required`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the world of sessions my friend.

By default django does its magic by using cookie based sessions to associate a particular client with a user.

A user can be either anonymous user that is just a visitor with little known information or an authenticated user which the system has authenticated using a backend.

More specifically the **django.contrib.auth** application deals with user authentication and it must be enabled on your installed apps to be able to have the different distinct users.

What it does is that when you log in for the first time it verifies that the client is a particular known user by adding a few variables in the session key and then rehashes it. This session string then contains information about the current user which it then stores into the database by default.

For subsequent requests it uses the **django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware** middleware to verify that the request with the session key belongs to a known session key from the backend storage. If it doesn't it just returns a response as a client with anonymous credentials.

Its important to realise that the session key is stored in the browsers cookie which you can inspect.

So when you accessing as a logged in user a profile page for example http://example.com/user/1 the application uses the keyword argument with the number 1 to get the user associated with that number.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
if request.user == user:
# Show your own user profile page
else:
# user is not the owner of the profile show public profile
```

That way you can differentiate requests.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a User Authentication System : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/

Here's specifically what you were looking for : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

Using which you can set Sessions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/

If you're using a different Django version simply change it in the URL and you'll get the corresponding links. You can't go wrong with the official documentation. Good luck !